# How to OpenVPN auto-reconnect on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4

I hope you are well.
I set up OpenVPN on VPS for 5 clients (but I only use 3). I noticed that OpenVPN automatically reboots every day at 4 am. So far so good; The problem is that of the 3 client devices, only two reconnect to OpenVPN and the other (Raspberry Pi4) does not reconnect to OpenVPN until I reboot raspberry pi itself.

I wanted help from you with a command that makes raspberry reconnect with OpenVPN when it reboots.

Note: The settings for raspberry pi are well done because when I reboot raspberry it reconnects to OpenVPN automatically, but when OpenVPN reboots, raspberry pi doesn't reconnect to OpenVPN.

Or if you would help me so that OpenVPN doesn't auto-reboot, just when I do.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Have a nice start of the year.

Good morning friends, I come here to bring the test results of the tips you gave me yesterday.

As you can see, OpenVPN on the raspberry pi4 client, at exactly 05:00:30, where the log shows (Jan 8 05:00:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd [399]: wlan0: carrier lost).

Remember that the OpenVPN server always restarts at this time (I don't know why and I didn't configure it). At least if I could disable this OpenVPN server autostart setting.

Updated
[image]

Comment: Scheduled `sudo service openvpn restart` on crontab?

Comment: Thanks. On Openvps server or openvpn client?

Comment: On vpn client, however, there is some solution if the vpnserver rebooting is a problem and you didn't configure like this.

Comment: Good. So what would be the solution? I honestly did not configure the reboot, it may be that the commands I used already include autostart but each command had its description and I read it carefully.
I would like to disable this setting.

Thanks in advance for your time and support

Comment: It might be useful. https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=22020

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can restart the openvpn client service on the Raspberry Pi.

Edit jobs list:

```
crontab -e
```

Add this line:

```
10 4 * * * service openvpn restart
```

It will restart the `openvpn` service of the Raspberry Pi every day at 04:10' AM.